# How to collect custom class object from stream in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<Flashcard, FlashcardStats> flashcards`. The Flashcard class contains two fields: String term and String definition. When I have to find specific flashcard from flashcards, how can I do it via Java 8 Streams? How can I collect Flashcard object or just definition field having only term?

For example:

```
private static String getWrongAnswerMessage(Map<Flashcard, FlashcardStats> flashcards, String term, String answer) {

Flashcard flashcard = flashcards.keySet().stream().filter(o -> o.getTerm().equals(term)).collect() //what now
```

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple `Flashcard`s with the same name? Maybe you just need `findFirst` or `findAny` and no collector at all.

Comment: There can't be two flashcards with the same term or with the same definition. I will try this.

Comment: Thank you @michalk, it works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming on one maching result

```java
Optional<String> term = flashcards.keySet()
                  .stream()
                  .filter(o->o.getTerm().equals(term))
                  .map(Flashcard::getTerm)
                  .findFirst();
```

Comment: Thank you, in your solution it should be Optional<String> but it works :)

Comment: @MrFisherman Thanks for pointing out the mistake, I have updated the answer